# Can we use mysql with MS SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are trying to configure SharePoint 2010. We realized that SQL Server license for SharePoint is very costly. We are now evaluating other options for SQL server. We would like to know whether we can use MySQL with SharePoint 2010. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

Not as the back end for Content databases. Only SQL server is supported.

Comment: Would have been *extremely* surprised if they supported anything *but* SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Why not install SQL Server Express R2? That is free.
See: http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/with-sharepoint-foundation-2010-use-sql-server-2008-express-r2/
(So that's an option if you're not storing many documents.)

Alternatively, look at processor licensing, as that is much cheaper then per user licensing. (Generally).

I doubt you need SQL Server Enterprise edition, so look at the Standard edition licence costs.

Comment: Express R2 with 10GB is a cheap alternative, +1.

Comment: In general, you really shouldn't consider express as an alternative if sharepoint is going to be instituted in a large organization. The more value people see in it, the more you'll have jumping on the SP band wagon and soon enough that size limit you have on Express is going to kill you, just like moving stuff over to a full SQL Server installation will.